# htaccess rewrite/redirect if last character is NOT a digit or slash

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site where I have a htaccess rule set to take the entire url, and forward it to my index file, using the below rule, with everything working fine.

```
#################################
# Magic Re-Writes DO NOT CHANGE #
#################################
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine on
  #RewriteBase /

  # Do Not apply if a specific file or folder exists
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  # The rules on how to rewrite the urls

  RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

So the below rule forwards http://mydomain.com/players/scoresheet/singlegame

to

http://mydomain.com/index.php?url=players/scoresheet/singlegame

However, I also need to ensure I cater for people forgetting the trailing slash in the url, something normally straight forward, however, I need to be able to force the final trailing slash ONLY if that last character is not numerical (or a slash obviously).

For Example, someone types;

http://mydomain.com/players/scoresheet/singlegame

I need the url in the browser to show as: http://mydomain.com/players/scoresheet/singlegame/

but still be forwarded to: http://mydomain.com/index.php?url=players/scoresheet/singlegame/

As said the exception to this will be if the last character already has the trailing slash, or is a numerical digit.

(Hope that makes sense)

Ok, heres what I have so far...

```
#######################################
#      Add trailing slash to url      #
#  unless last character is a number  #
#######################################

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} [^0-9/]$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

#################################
# Magic Re-Writes DO NOT CHANGE #
#################################
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  # Do Not apply if a specific file or folder exists
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  # The rules on how to rewrite the urls

  RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem with this is although it *seems* to get the adding of the slash to the url, it also addes the index.php as well, so what I end up with, is:

Visit: http://mydomain.com/players/scoresheet/singlegame

get url rewritten to: http://mydomain.com/index.php?url=players/scoresheet/singlegame/

The slash is added, but I need it to do so without display the index part.

I have gone backwards and forwards, with many different outcomes (usually outright failures, or loops).

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule is correct, but it's blindly redirecting even when it's not supposed to. The URL that you have above is *probably* not what it's getting rewritten to. You have it as:

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php?url=players/scoresheet/singlegame/
```

But I'm willing to bet it's really something like:

```
# note the slash here--------v
http://mydomain.com/index.php/?url=players/scoresheet/singlegame/
```

Because after the URI is internally rewritten and routed to `/index.php`, the rewrite engine loops again and the redirect catches it, and redirects `/index.php` to `/index.php/`. So you need to add the same exclusion conditions that you have in your routing rule:

So change:

```
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} [^0-9/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

to either:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} [^0-9/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

or:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} [^0-9/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you ever so much. I thought I would have gone insane for moment back there.